# JQuery / Javascript popup box and form submission creation

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, popup

I have a jquery/javascript question. For a site I am working on in PHP/JQuery I have the need to create a dialogue box with an ok/cancel button and a message and then submit a form based on if the user says ok or not. I know in javascript I can create a new window that links to a styled page and then I can do a select for if the user hits the ok button and submit the windows parent form using that but the last time I coded something similar to it I felt like it took a lot of lines of code and was wondering if JQuery supported dialogue box creation and if I could do some similar functionality using it (with hopefully less lines of code since everytime I use jquery instead of standard javascript it seems like it really reduces my codebase). If anyone knows of a resource to learn how to do this I would appreciate a link or a second of your time for some pointers.

Thanks!

Comment: use google. this isn't a specific code question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something along the lines of the [jquery ui dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).